# Importing and rendering 3D object

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

am a complete noob when it comes to 3D and Blender. This is what I want to do:

I want to create some videos of 3D spaceship models. I have found several superb models on sketchfab and downloaded them. Now, I want to finalize them so I can use them in After Effects. When I import them into Blender, I get the solid. The colors and textures are exactly as I need them, so is it possible to import the entire model, not just the grey solid and export it in a different format, one that would be compatible with After Effects? Thanks for your patience with a total noob!!

Danny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To import OBJ (object) use this

[image]

### To Export 3DS use this

Follow the image guide as far as I understand is what you are looking for, if you think you need more information be more specific in your question

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. My apologies let me explain better. I downloaded a model from Sketchfab. I extracted it and it came with a .obj and several .jpg. I want to import the .obj and the .jpg into Blender so it looks exactly the same as the model on Sketchfab. Then I want to render it in a format that I can use in After Effets... probably using the Cinema 4D Light that comes with After Effects.

Comment: no problem, it's the same process, import the obj file in blender and export in 3DS, if you can't do it, let me know and I'll put the answer later because now I'm busy

Comment: @DannyBouchard check now

Comment: Hello, I tinkered with it and managed to get to the render and the output tabs. I just need to figure out why when I hit F12, the model is too big in scale. Am assuming it could be due to my camera view. I'll figure it out eventually, watching videos on Youtube to instruct me.

Comment: @DannyBouchard mark the accepted com answer, you can search here more than on youtube the answers are more punctual

Comment: the problem of the scale already belongs to a completely different question, this was answered only you need to mark it as accepted